# Change database query with aspect

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, jhipster

I have a running Webapplication which I created by using jhipster. It allows users to log-in and persist stuff to the database. 
Now I want to open my application to different organisations, so I need to seperate them properly. My idea was to create a table with all organisations and every other entity gets a field organisation_id. Now the point is that if I invoke a database query with Hibernate, for example getAll(), I want to modify the query such that it only returns data that belongs to the current customer. I was thinking about achieving this with an aspect(although I have no idea how to). But I would love to hear your ideas.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is well described [in this article](http://www.ekito.fr/people/inject-multitenancy-in-your-spring-web-application/) though there is always a risk that data isolation could be overcomed. Hibernate has described well the 3 approaches in [their dev guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) but since 4.0 the [partitioned data approach has always been postponed to next release](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6054) (now 6.0).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Spring Security @PostFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter)

Comment: Thank you. That is probably an interesting feature, but the solution doesn't scale very well. I have to modify the search query directly to only get the right datasets